# When was "rush" first used to describe a sudden intense feeling?

Tags: etymology

I see different definitions of the word date back to the [14th century](https://www.etymonline.com/word/rush#etymonline_v_16661), but none for the meaning of a sudden intense feeling. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rush) didn't have that information either.

Is it a modern definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It developed in the 18th and 19th centuries from a term meaning a rapidly growing emotion to something closer to the modern sense of a sudden, overpoweringly intense feeling.

The modern sense is what the OED gives as definition 2 b of "rush": "A rushing sensation in the body; a surge of euphoria, excitement, or energy, esp. one induced by drugs or some other stimulant."

The first reference cited is 1834. It refers to a rush of despair not euphoria, although the latter is the more common sense today: "He felt a rush as of a torrent to his temples;—his eyes grew dizzy—he was stunned by the greatness of his despair." (Edward Bulwer-Lytton)

From 1895: "This one felt a rush in his veins, a throb like the first which drove him on."
(Deas Cromarty, pen name of Elizabeth Sophia Watson). There's another from James Joyce in 1922 which seems less clear out of context: "He couldn't get a connection. Only, you know, sensation. A dry rush." The sense specifically referring to drugs (which you don't seem to ask about) comes from the 1970s: the OED cites *Frendz* magazine in 1971.

This sense apparently derives from a weaker 18th century sense (2 a: "A surge of a particular emotion.") where it means an emotion coming over somebody, but probably less strongly and overpoweringly than the modern sense. For instance: " The sudden Rush of painful Ecstasie!" (1722) or "Heard you that rush of woe." (1770) Talk of "rush" in the sense of emotion moving fast is a natural development from the sense of sudden movement or flow, which dates to around 1500.

Source: "rush, n.2, adv., and adj." OED Online. Oxford University Press, March 2021. Web. 10 May 2021.

Comment: Thanks. I completely forgot to check the OED.

Comment: I sense misrepresentation of the source and doubt your interpretation. It might be correct that the particular sense was fairly recent, as rare as it is (from an ESL perspective). "sudden rush of ... " besides "adrenalin rush" vel sim. are set collocations. *rush* in this sense pertaining to *emotion* seems to be from ellipses. Otherhand, German *Überraschung* "surprise" (16C; cp. *rash* "hasty") shows a common drift maybe from *to rush (an enemy)*, but this' less than clear (DWDS doubts \*kers- "to run"). So that "rapidly growing" versus "sudden, overpoweringly" seems to me a false dichotomy.